# Python (Selenium) loop

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop

Right now, I have the following code. I'm having issues with followLoop2 and followLoop3. The followLoop2 expands folders that contain pictures. Right now though, it expands all folders and then goes to loop followLoop3. I don't want this to happen though. I want it to expand 1 folder with followLoop2, then go to followLoop3 until there's no option there to continue, then go back to followLoop2, expand the next folder. This should continue until there is no folder to open anymore.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this? Much thanks!

```
#Function to export data
def loop_function():

    #Search client
    searchCustomerButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ibSearchPatient"]')
    searchCustomerButton.click()   

    #Loop client ID's
    followLoop = range(2, 999)
    for x in followLoop:

        xpath = '//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Main_ctl00_RadGrid_Patienten_ctl00__'
        xpath += str(x)
        xpath += '"]/td[3]'
        
        #Click on cliënt ID
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()

        #Find client ID box
        testID = driver.find_element_by_id('TxtPatientNr').get_property('value')
        print(testID)

        #Click on Documentbeheer
        documentbeheerButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Main_MainLeft_MainLeftPageMenu_MenuModulePages"]/ul/li[3]/a/span')
        documentbeheerButton.click()

        time.sleep(2)

        #Click on show filter
        showAllFilter = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Main_ctl00_RadGridDocumenten_ctl00_ctl03_ctl01_PageSizeComboBox_Arrow"]')
        showAllFilter.click()

        time.sleep(2)

        #Click on show 50
        showAll = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Main_ctl00_RadGridDocumenten_ctl00_ctl03_ctl01_PageSizeComboBox_DropDown"]/div/ul/li[5]')
        showAll.click()

        #Loop folder photo's
        followLoop2 = range(0,10)
        for i in followLoop2:
            try:
                xpath2 = '//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Main_ctl00_RadGridDocumenten_ctl00__'
                xpath2 += str(i)
                xpath2 += '"]/td[1]'

                #Click on photo map
                driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath2).click()

                time.sleep(2)
            
            #If no photo folder, start function over
            except NoSuchElementException:
                print('Getting exception!')

                followLoop3 = range(0,20)
                for k in followLoop3:
                    xpath3 = '//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Main_ctl00_RadGridDocumenten_ctl00_ctl15_Detail40__'
                    xpath3 += str(i)
                    xpath3 += ':0_'
                    xpath3 += str(k)
                    xpath3 += '"]/td[2]'

                    #Click on picture file
                    driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath3).click()

                    time.sleep(2)

                    #Click on image
                    imageButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Main_ctl00_imgbtnDoctype"]')
                    imageButton.click()

                    time.sleep(1)

                    #Click on download
                    downloadButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="downloadButton"]')
                    downloadButton.click()

                    #Click on close
                    closeButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btnZorgAnnuleren"]')
                    closeButton.click()
```

Comment: It seems that you're overwriting your `xpath3` with a constant after constructing it, are you sure you want this?

Comment: @Talon, sorry that's not supposed to be there. I was debugging a bit to see where it was going wrong. That isn't there when I try the code. I have edited it in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your third loop is within your exception handling, it does one iteration of the second loop, has no exception, does the next iteration of the second loop, and so on, until you get the `NoSuchElementException`, which then starts the third loop.

You want to unindent the third loop by one level, so that it happens after the `try-except`-block, and then have a `continue` or `return` after `print('Getting exception!')`

You could also make use of the `else`-block of the try-construct [(syntax here, `else` will be entered if there was no exception)](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and put your third loop there.